# I have a textfile and I want to replace a string in it with empty string but

Tags: c#, sql, regex

I also want to take off the string after that till the next comma, and if that string is after "select" then I want to replace anything after select and till the next comma.
For example:
select a.column, a.myID, a.studentID from mytable

I have many textfiles like this so I need something that takes care of it like if I want to replace column with empty string it should look like after replace
select a.myID, a.studentID from mytable

and If I want to replace myID with empty string it should look like this after replace
select a.column, a.studentID from mytable

and If i want to replace studentID with empty string it should look like this
select a.column, a.myID from mytable.

Thanks
I'm working in C# I was thinking of using regex but can't come up with a regex.

Comment: just a side project I'm trying to learn c# and making some sql querries and ouputing them to a textfile. Just looking for a better way to do it without changing a column everytime by giong in a file and just by passing column name to the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need >>

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
  static void Main()
  {
    string input = "select ceiling(a.interest) as interest, a.myID as mID, a.studentID as sID from mytable";
    string column = "a.myID";
    string pattern = "((?<=\\bselect)\\s+[^,]*\\b" + Regex.Escape(column) + "\\b[^,]*\\s*,?|\\s*,\\s*[^,]*\\b" + Regex.Escape(column) + "\\b[^,]*(?=(?:,|\\sfrom\\b)))";
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Console.WriteLine(output);
  }
}
```

Test this code [here](http://ideone.com/3KVQ3).

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I didn't make myself clear. I could have something like select b.portfolio, ceiling(a.interest) as interest, so if I want to remove interest it should remove ceiling(a.interest) as interest,

Comment: string pattern = @"((?<!,)\s*\w" + columnName + @"\w\s*,?|\s*,\s*" + columnName + @"\b)";

Comment: in the column I dont want to say a.myID because in the querry it cold be b.myID or c.myID........I just wanna say column = myID

Comment: @Maurh - **Did you at least test it** with such column value..?

Comment: There is a problem, like in your example if you have a comma after from and try to replace studentID it will remove everything till that comma

Comment: @Maurh - Replace last `[^,]*` with `[^,]*?`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "replace anything after select and till the next comma" in C# using a regex, the following will work:

```
Regex.Replace("select a.myID, a.studentID from mytable", @"select\s[^\,]+", "select newColumn");
```

However, if you need to keep the table name/alias, you may need to modify that slightly:

```
Regex.Replace("select a.myID, a.studentID from mytable", @"select\s([^\.]+\.)[^\,]+", "select $1newColumn");
```